# randomly select a fixed number of rows in each group in SQL server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do a SQL query to find some entries from a large table.

table:

```
 id  value1 value2 
 ny  35732  8023 
 ny   732  23
 ny   292  109
 nj   8232  813
 nj   241   720
 nj   590   287
```

I need to **randomly** select 2 entries **from each distinct id group s**uch that

```
 id  value1 value2 
 ny  35732  8023 
 ny   292  109
 nj   8232  813
 nj   590   287
```

My SQL code:

```
 select top 2 * from my_table group by id value1 value2
```

But, it is not what I want.

I also need to insert the result into a table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` and use `NEWID()` to generate a random `ORDER`:

*EDIT: I replaced `CHECKSUM(NEWID())` with  `NEWID()` since I cannot prove which is faster and `NEWID()` is I think the most used.*

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY NEWID())
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    id, value1, value2
FROM Cte
WHERE RN <= 2
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46710/1/0)

The fiddle should show different result among different runs.

---

If you're inserting this to another table use this subquery version:

```
INSERT INTO yourNewTable(id, value1, value2)
    SELECT
        id, value1, value2
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY NEWID())
        FROM tbl
    )t
    WHERE RN <= 2
```

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: I need to insert the result into a table. But, I got error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'. I put your code as a subquery as a table.

Comment: I suggest you read more on `CTE`s, or subquery for that matter.

Comment: You can `INSERT` with the `cte` version (just move `INSERT INTO` below the `cte`), and `CHECKSUM()` is not doing anything useful here, `NEWID()` is sufficient.

Comment: What is the need of `CHECKSUM` in `Order by`

Comment: Transforms the `NEWID()` into an `INT`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan - but why you need to do the convertion

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE  @Table1 TABLE 
    (id varchar(2), value1 int, value2 int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (id, value1, value2)
VALUES
    ('ny', 35732, 8023),
    ('ny', 732, 23),
    ('ny', 292, 109),
    ('nj', 8232, 813),
    ('nj', 241, 720),
    ('nj', 590, 287)
;


SELECT *
FROM   @Table1 T
WHERE 
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*) 
            FROM    @Table1  TT
            WHERE T.id = TT.id AND 
                  T.value1 >= TT.value1
        ) <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is all over this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT *
  FROM Table1
  ORDER BY NEWID()
```

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc441928.aspx for more examples